# Can you please give me an example for Switch Connection Using Telnet library on Robot framework

Tags: robotframework

I Don't how to use the Switch connection for the following test case.
Following one is my test case...So for this how can i switch the connections from R1 to R2 & again to R2 :

```
*** Settings ***
Library           Telnet

*** Variables ***
${R1}             20.1.1.1
${R2}             20.1.1.2
${username1}      naveen
${password1}      kumar
${username2}      hi
${password2}      bye

*** Test Cases ***
telnet4
    Open Connection    ${R1}    prompt=username    prompt=password    alias=conn01
    Write    ${username1}
    Write    ${password1}
    Read Until    >
    Write    enable
    Read Until    Password
    Write    ${password1}
    Write    R1
    Read Until    \#
    Write    show ip route
    Read Until    \#
    Open Connection    ${R2}    prompt=username    prompt=password    alias=conn02
    Write    ${username2}
    Write    ${password2}
    Read Until    >
    Write    enable
    Read Until    Password
    Write    ${password2}
    Write    R2
    Read Until    \#
    Write    show ip route
    Read Until    \#
    Switch Connection    conn01
    Switch Connection    conn02
```

Comment: Looks like you already have a solution, Switch Connection works exactly the way you need it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to change a previously set variable, the `Set Variable` keyword should do just fine, assuming the variable only needs to be available in its native context. Otherwise, `Set Global Variable` is what you're looking for.

Example of use of `Set Variable`:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Change a Variable
    ${thing} =  Set Variable  some
    ${thing} =  Set Variable  some1
    Log to Console  ${thing}
```

Variables declared in a variable table (like you did) can be declared based on other variables, so if you don't care if a variable is global, just declare it locally to keep the mutability.